# MPI communication complexity

Tags: parallel-processing, communication, complexity-theory, mpi

I'm studying the communication complexity of a parallel implementation of Quicksort in MPI and I've found something like this in a book:

> "A single process gathers p regular samples from each of the other p-1 processes. Since relatively few values are being passed, message latency is likely to be the dominant term of this step. Hence the communication complexity of the gather is O(log p)" (O is actually a theta and p is the number of processors).

The same affirmation is made for the broadcast message.

Why are these group communications complexity O(log p)? Is it because the communication is done using some kind of tree-based hierarchy?

What if latency is not the dominant term and there's a lot of data being sent? Would the complexity be O(n log (p)) where n would be the size of the data being sent divided by the available bandwidth?

And, what about the communication complexity of an MPI_Send() and an MPI_Recv()?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the value of `p`?

Comment: oh sorry, p is the number of processors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, gather and scatter are implemented using (depending on the particular MPI release) for instance binomial trees, hypercube, linear array or 2D square mesh. An all-gather operations may be implemented using an hypercube and so on.

For a gather or scatter, let lambda be the latency and beta the bandwidth. Then log p steps are required. Suppose you are sending n integers each represented using 4 bytes. The time to send them is

[image]

This is O(log p) when n = O(1) and O(log p + n) otherwise.
For a broadcast, the time required is

[image]

which is O(log p) when n = O(1) and O(n log p) otherwise.

Finally, for point-to-point communications like MPI_Send(), if you are sending n integers the communication complexity is O(n). When n = O(1) then the complexity is obviously O(1).